# Count nodes with at least one child having the attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I have been running around in circles with this. I would like to count the number of workers that have at least one attribute changing. If the first name changes, thats 1. If last name changes, thats 1. If both changes, thats 1.

In my system, change is represented by a node having prior value - similar to below (pseudo):

```
<!-- XML -->

<Slave_Group>
<Slave>
    <Personal>
        <First_Name PriorValue="John">Jacob</First_Name>
        <Last_Name>Smith</Last_Name>
    </Personal>
</Slave>
<Slave>
    <Personal>
        <First_Name>Mary</First_Name>
        <Last_Name PriorValue="Peterson">O'Reilly</Last_Name>
    </Personal>
</Slave>
<Slave>
    <Personal>
        <First_Name PriorValue="Tim">Eric</First_Name>
        <Last_Name PriorValue="Heidecker">Wareheim</Last_Name>
    </Personal>
</Slave>
</Slave_Group>
```

The following XSLT is applied to the XML:

```
<!-- XSLT -->

<variable name="numNameChanges" select="count(//Slave_Group/Slave/Personal/(First_Name[@PriorValue] or Last_Name[@PriorValue]))"/>
```

The value I would like to get would be **numNameChanges = 3**. This is not the case. I am getting strange results when I run on the sample file. I am prepared to use a template and count the return of that template - but I am not sure what to match for etc... I have also thought about grouping but I think my spec is not so complicated that I need to get into complex functionality. Maybe I'm being naive.

Is there a way to conditionally count the nodes?

Comment: Hopefully minor point, but for the sake of political correctness you might want to clarify the context of your data. I'm desperately hoping this is some sort of historical record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several syntax issues in there, most notably redundant parentheses and `Prior_Value` instead of `PriorValue`. Try:

```
count(/Slave_Group/Slave[Personal/First_Name/@PriorValue or Personal/Last_Name/@PriorValue])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This works for what I want. Will experiment with the position of the square brackets to get a better understanding.

Comment: Anything inside the square brackets is a predicate (a test). We are counting `Slave` elements that pass the test. The test here is the existence of a specific descendant node. The path to that node is relative to the node being tested.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this:

```
count(//Slave_Group/Slave/Personal[*/@PriorValue])
```

This counts any `Personal` elements that have any child elements with a `PriorValue` attribute.